# Set XML as default output format in ASP.NET Core 2.0

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi

I have added **XmlFormaterExtensions** like below code which works fine with an **Accept** header. My query is:

1. How do I set **XML as default o/p format** instead of JSON?
2. Is there any trick to set the XML for-matter to **Camel Case** instead of Pascal Case

*I am using ASP.NET Core 2.0 (Asking for o/p format only)*

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services){
    services.AddMvc()
        .AddXmlFormaterExtensions()
        .AddJsonOptions(options => {
            options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver();
     });}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I set XML as default o/p format instead of JSON?

For this requirement, try code below:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        services.AddMvc(options => {
            options.OutputFormatters.Insert(0, new XmlDataContractSerializerOutputFormatter());
        }).SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a ton @tao-zhou