# How do I change the default response content type in an ASP.NET Core API?

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi

I am re-implementing a legacy API as a `ASP.NET Core web API`.  I have implemented [content negotiation](https://code-maze.com/content-negotiation-dotnet-core/) and it is working fine - all the actions support both `JSON` and `XML` response formats based on the `Accept header` in the request.  My issue is that the original API defaulted to XML if no Accept header was specified, while my ASP.NET Core API is defaulting to JSON.  How do I make the default response content type XML when there is no Accept header?

Comment: What version of ASP.NET Core are you use?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set XML as default output format in ASP.NET Core 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54541551/set-xml-as-default-output-format-in-asp-net-core-2-0)

Answer (score 2):

You can configure it in the `Startup`

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        services.AddMvc(options => {
            options.OutputFormatters.Insert(0, new XmlDataContractSerializerOutputFormatter());
        }).SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
    }
```

Or just use the attribute `Produces` in your Controller.

```
[Produces("application/xml")]
public class MyController()
{
 ...
}
```